# How to Check if paginate button is enabled or disabled

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

I have a webpage where there are options to navigate to other pages at the bottom.
For example, like previous,1,2,3,4,Next.
I want to check if the 'Next' Button is enabled or disabled using Java Selenium Webdriver.
Can someone help me in this scenario? Please refer the following HTML snippet

```
<div id="paginate">
<ul class="pagination">
    <li id="paginate_previous" class="paginate_button previous" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button " tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button " tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="paginate_next" class="paginate_button next disabled" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by utilizing the getAttribute() function.
The "Next" Button class attribute changes whenever the button gets disabled and I utilized this aspect to resolved the issue.

In while loop I checked if the class is equal to current class and as soon as the class changes the condition returns false and control is out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by `paginate_next` id and use `isEnabled()`:

```
WebElement nextPage = driver.findElement(By.id("paginate_next"));
nextPage.isEnabled();  // returns true/false
```

Comment: I am working on the functionality to check if the "Next"  button is enabled. If it is enabled then I have to perform some tasks in a while loop and if its not enabled then I need to exit the loop.
However, when I try the above code, it does not exit form while loop and goes in the infinite loop (total pages to navigate by next button are 2 and after 2 pages the next button is visible on webpage but its disabled). I am unable to exit from the while loop using above condition. Is there any alternative solution to this issue?

Comment: @KetanDeopujari okay, got it, thanks for the explanation. For starters, can you share a link to the webpage so that I can play around and reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have posted the answer below. Thanks for your help.